# The result of !dumpheap is wrong

Tags: .net, debugging, windbg, sos

I run the  command "!dumpheap -min 62 -max 64 " and found the following result, and we found the Count of string is 43,149,740 , however the total size of them is just 5,146,310 bytes, so the total size  is wrong , right?

```
Statistics:
              MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
00007fff0faaf518        1          100 System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.InternalPrimitiveTypeE[]
00007fff0fb22c98        2          200 System.Int16[]
00007fff0fb06888       36         3532 System.Byte[]
00007fff0fb02090      174        17124 System.Char[]
00007fff0fb03920      545        54500 System.Int32[]
00007fff0fb00e08 **43149740**      **5146310** System.String
Total 43150498 objects
```

Comment: It capatured from the prod env, so cann't repro it .

Comment: Were you able to try the code from the answer?

Comment: Yes, the test for the sample is the same as you in my environment, it seems the issue happened in special conditions, BTW, the size of the dump is 7G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information given in the question might not be enough to definitely tell the source of the problem. This might be a version specific issue which I can't reproduce, or your heap is broken (run `!verifyheap`).

The following program creates string of length 64 (128 bytes of data), length 200 (400 bytes of data) and length 1024 (2048 bytes of data).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace StringSizeDumpheap
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> smallstrings = CreateList(1000, 64);
            List<string> mediumstrings = CreateList(1000, 200);
            List<string> largestrings = CreateList(1000, 1024);
            const string dbginfo = "Debug now. Use !dumpheap -min -max with 0n140/0n144, 0n400/0n440 and 0n2000/0n2200.";
            Console.WriteLine(dbginfo);
            Console.ReadLine();
            // Access strings to prevent optimization
            smallstrings[0] = "";
            mediumstrings[0] = "";
            largestrings[0] = "";
        }

        private static List<string> CreateList(int count, int size)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                list.Add(new string('x', size));
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

With that demo program, WinDbg + SOS gives the expected results on WinDbg 6.2.9200 (program compiled as .NET 4.5.2, 32 bit preferred, Debug build)

```
0:004> !dumpheap -stat -mt 70dde918        -min 0n140 -max 0n144
Statistics:
      MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
70dde918     1002       142284 System.String
Total 1002 objects

0:004> !dumpheap -stat -mt 70dde918        -min 0n380 -max 0n500
Statistics:
      MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
70dde918     1000       414000 System.String
Total 1000 objects

0:004> !dumpheap -stat -mt 70dde918        -min 0n2000 -max 0n2200
Statistics:
      MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
70dde918     1000      2062000 System.String
Total 1000 objects
```